# How to assign a user to a group at signup using django-userena?

Tags: django, django-views, registration, usergroups

I would like to separate users into two different groups, employer or 
employee, at signup. I'm using django-userena and for the employer group I'm thinking of using a clone of the same signup view except with a different url tied to it.

So whoever signs up at url(r'^signup/employer/$) will be added to the employer group with

```
new user = user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name=employer))
```

added to the view. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited**: `form.save()` returns the user just created. You have then to simply add it to your group. Your view should look something like:

```
form = signup_form() 
if request.method == 'POST': 
    form = signup_form(request.POST, request.FILES) 
    if form.is_valid(): 
        user = form.save()
        user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='employer'))
```

I would also consider using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/), if what you want to do is to add *every* user to your *employer* group. Something like this will add each newly created user to it, and will allow you to use the default `signup` view from `userena`:

```
# somewhere, in your models.py file
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='myproject.myapp.models.user_post_save_handler')
def user_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """ This method is executed whenever an user object is saved                                                                                     
    """
    if created:
        instance.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='employer'))
```

Comment: Currently the view has: `form = signup_form()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = signup_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save() `
The link to the view [link]https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/views.py [link]

Comment: Maybe right before `user = form.save()` on the view, I can add `new_user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='employer'))` and I think this is all that is needed in the new view? Because the view calls a form that has a save method that creates the user already. [userena_forms](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/forms.py)

Comment: thanks for helping me. I did this in my app.forms                 `class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):                                           def save(self):
new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()           new_user.save()  new_user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='employer'))
return new_user` and added this to urls.py `url(r'^accounts/signup/employer$',
'userena.views.signup',
    {'signup_form': SignupFormExtra}),` at accounts/signup adds me to the employer group. I only want to be in the employer group at accounts/signup/employer

Comment: okay that makes sense. Then your solution should work, just add an URL on 'accounts/signup/employer' with your custom form as you did, and another URL on 'accounts/signup' with the default form for other users (pay attention on security issues, though...) your custom form works, just remove the `new_user.save()` since it's been already done by the superclass.